# Why is the narrative of Moses growing up in Pharaoh's house important?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, moshe-rabbeinu, yetziat-mitzrayim

I begin with the assertion that nothing is arbitrary in the Torah and the history followed the big plan as envisioned by the Creator.

The narrative of Moses' origin is fascinating but its necessity is puzzling. I ask myself, how would the story be different had Moses survived in Amram's house, grown up in Egypt, traveling to Midyan, experiencing the bush, and coming back as the leader of the Hebrews.

The numerous Midrashim add colorful details to Moses' biography but nothing that seems to pertain to the narrative of Exodus.

Why is the narrative of Moses growing up in Pharaoh's house important?